# How to fix signature error when invoking lambda-url connection with IAM authentication mode in Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Has any one tried lambda-url connections using python.
When iam trying the authentication with "IAM" mode.
i am unable to invoke lambda-url due to signature error.

I checked but couldnt find any relevant help material.

I am able to get response in postman, but not using codes

Get a proper response for get / put request

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i willl edit the subject line and add more context